# How can I add Permissions Table To ASPNET Identity Mechanism

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity-2

ASPNET Identity mechanism has users table, roles table, claims table and these relations tables from them. I want to add permissions table to these mechanism.

Should Database contains the permissions table? Because, permissions will spesific and I should write code these privileges. For example; CanCreateUser, CanEditUser, etc.

Which one user table or role table releated with permissions? Or, both them?

Is there anyone, implementing same mechanism and has code sample?

Comment: Majorly the role table is used for access restriction. For roles you can apply restrictions to different methods and pages.

Comment: Do you really want to map detailed permissions to individual users?  Because the roles (and/or the claims) let you do this more conveniently.

Comment: @Gaurav Role table not enough for me. Because, I want to set dynamically ability for users. For example, we have account role that has some users. The users have same role but i want to set some restrictions. Maybe one user can do all things(CanAddExpense, CanEditExpense vs). Another some users who have same role only can do adding expense(CanAddExpense) and editing expense(CanEditExpense). Another some users who have same role only can do deleting expense(CanDeleteExpense).

Comment: @Gaurav  According to your response, I can set role to an action/a controller. So, users of role access to them. But the roles be as like as permissions. I think, a role must define a permission set. Also, i will need again role groups. Nothing has changed. I just misinterpreted some structures(like the role table)

Comment: @bommelding I will set some permission definition(e.g. CanAddExpense, CanEditExpense, CanDeleteExpense) to action or controller with attribute and i will set dynamically these ability to users or roles. Claims only store some values. But they are not store permissions. Claims store some low importance information. (e.g. last login time, gender, etc)

Comment: @muratbaseren as you said you need to assign permissions dynamically to roles then you need to create another table with the name Capabilities which will be mapped to the users directly and you will apply a filter for Roles+Capabilities on your controller or methods. Roles will be broad category of permissions and capabilities you can use to manage permissions at granular level.

Comment: @Gaurav According to your response,  What about my role names?

Comment: @muratbaseren, I think the main two roles should be admin and user. As I don't know the entire functionality so I can not tell all of them, you can add some between admin and user as per your needs.

Comment: @Gaurav So, how can i seperate same role users who has some different privillages(user0 & user1: only canAdd+canEdit - user2:  only canRead - user3 & user4: only canDelete). I can said my action names that are called CreateExpense, EditExpense, DeleteExpense, ReadExpense in accounting controller. MVC5 project and I want to check access for user with Authorize attribute.

Comment: @muratbaseren roles will decide the access to entire module and then small permissions should be managed using capabilities. For your case I think Edit, Update or Delete should be handled using capabilities.

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav, I decided use grouping roles into named as Security Group table.  Security Groups are container for roles. (e.g. Accounting) Roles are  capabilities for Security Group. Because [Authorize] attribute uses Roles in MVC. So, I thought, role names like that ExpenseCreator, ExpenseModifier etc. Security Group related Roles and Users as different tables. Many-to-many relation. Briefly, Security Groups relation many roles and many users. Also, I am adding roles of security group to UserRoles table for [Authorize] attribute to use them. Maybe, I could not explain in here :)